# How can I make delete trigger run only once for all deleted records?

Tags: apex, trigger, batch

I must run two Batches after Case records are deleted. The problem is that records enter the delete process one by one **UPD: if you delete records from SOQL or multiple records from the UI**. Therefore, if I delete 50 Case records, 100 batches are scheduled.

```
trigger MyCaseTrigger on Case (before insert, before update, 
                           after update, after insert, after delete) {
     //...
     if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isAfter){
        //RunTwoBatches
    }
}
```

**Is there a way to make batches run only once, as soon as the last case record is deleted?**

**Update:**
You can achieve such behavior by deleting records from the SOQL
[image: Deleting 10 records]

[image: After delete is triggered for each record 10 times in total.]

Comment: why the records are deleted one by one and not in bulk?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. Could you please give us a little more background about why you need to delete records one by one? A good practice in the Apex development is to bulkify you logic as much as possible. Please, have a look at [Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers) Trailhead module, especially at the [Bulk Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) Triggers Unit. Cheers!

Comment: @Damecek that's the question. I don't know why, it is just the way salesforce works. You can try creating 10 Case records and add the after delete trigger "System.debug(Trigger.old.size())". You'll see 1.

Comment: @PrzemysławDługoszewski-Tamoń I don't need to delete them one by one. I must run two batches once, as soon as the last Case is deleted. I expected them to enter the delete process just like the insert process - in a bulk.

Comment: From developer console if we delete records it deletes one record at a time even if we delete multiple records, so other option is query these records in Anonymous Apex and delete using delete DML.

Comment: Your first issue is that your trigger runs both before and after delete, and since you do not check this state in the logic you obviously call the batch twice for each DML *scope* passed to the trigger. A scope can be any number from 1 to 200 records, being a (sub-)set of the record(s) deleted (or created or updated etc., depending on which event(s) your trigger listens for) in a single DML. You need to change your other code to avoid individually deleting cases, and make it perform a bulk delete by collecting the IDs of cases to delete then perform a single "delete" DML operation.